# Is it safe to use bootstrap 4 since it is in alpha release?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, frontend

My website currently uses bootstrap 3. I am going to do a revamp of the same website. If I use bootstrap 4, even though it is still in alpha release, will it cause problems?

If yes, what kind of problems are we talking about?

Comment: Why do you want to use bootstrap 4 instead of 3?

Comment: You answered your question in the title... 'alpha-release'. So of course there could be some changes since this is not the final full release.

Comment: Because I want my site to use advanced grid system that bootstrap 4 brings!

Comment: @bloC , I understand that there are going to be changes in the final release. But is it safe to assume that the changes in the final release won't affect my website drastically?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not in the developer team of bootstrap, so I can't say that for sure. Assuming that they develop like every other team, even they can't say - but it's rather unlikely that the final release will affect your website drastically. 

But you should not forget that it is never recommended to use a beta or even an alpha version of something for production.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, when a lib isn't in a stable version, means that something in the way you use that code, or all available features it offers, can change, so it's not safe for production because that can break your code.

Answer (score 5):

Rule of thumb:

Any piece of software not in stable version, final version or release version is prone of having lots of bugs.

Aplha versions are worse, since they can change their behavior or functionalities and haven't reached to the testing part yet.

So it is not safe for a stable production environment.